# Multiple persistence units are not loading

Tags: java, websphere, openjpa

I was struck , please help on this. My life is happy(Everything is working) when I was using 6 and WebSphere 7.5, but now, we have to migrate to  Java 7, WebSphere 8.5.5.12.
My requirement is like, same DB for 3 countries with different schema, all beans are same for 3 countries, but when I am trying to get persistence unit for SG, it is returning default HK one.

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="MY_HK">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyProjHK" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
         <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="openJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"></property>
</bean> 

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="MY_IN">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyProjIN" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="openJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistenceIN.xml"></property>
</bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="MY_SG">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyProjSG" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="openJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistenceSG.xml"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Is ths MY_IN persistent unit correct ? Is it only the MY_SG that is not loaded correctly ?

Comment: Yes My_IN is loading properly , problem with MY_SG is loading with default configuration

Comment: tried with single persistence.xml, but still not loading other countries, for all taking default country.

Comment: Seems to be some issue in WebSphere version, moved to the sub folder , its working as expected now.